# loading only some images in HTML and angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

[In this images shows what happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AUWh.jpg) 
HTML code is here- In this some of my images showing in webpage and some of is not..how should i fix it

```
<img src="img/uploadFiles/{{room.imageLocation.split('//')[6]}}/{{room.imageLocation.split('-')[1]}}" alt="Image Loading Failed"/>
```

Comment: If possible try to change the image path and I don't think those are valid file names

Comment: this is a case that *really* needs a [mcve] to understand what the problem is;  it's not possible to reproduce the issue from that screenshot which has **very unusual** filenames, especially without knowing the data you are working from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`ng-src`** instead of **`src`** when you are binding images

```
<img  ng-src="img/uploadFiles/{{room.imageLocation.split('//')[6]}}/{{room.imageLocation.split('-')[1]}}" alt="Image Loading Failed"/>
```

Comment: i used..but same result as the above image i posted

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: that is strange. check in network tab. or inspect the element

Comment: yes..the path and the image name's showing correctly..but image not loading..is there any way that i can contact you privately

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="img/uploadFiles/{{room.imageLocation.split('//')[6]}}/{{room.imageLocation.split('-')[1]}}" alt="Image Loading Failed" onError="this.src='./assets/img/placeholder.png'" />
```

Comment: still no..some of image loading and some of are not..both are in same format